# Including custom header file in ROS2 CMakeList

Tags: ros2, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to create a ROS2 package, which has a custom header file, and links to other header files downloaded from GitHub (in this case WiringPi).

For doing this, I understand that I must place my custom header file inside of the /include/package_name directory, but I cannot link it to the source file. I'm trying to following the documentation of [ament_cmake](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html) for "Adding files and headers", "Adding dependencies" and "Building a Library". Honestly, I don't really understand the documentation very well, and the lack of examples are making it hard for me to implement it myself.

Could anyone assist me with understanding how I can link my header file to my source file (e.g. through a sample CMakeList/package.xml), and with adding e.g. the [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/reference/serial-library/) to the code?

I'm currently following [this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/380079/how-to-write-header-file-for-ros-2-publisher/), and using the same files+filenames, but the source file still isn't able to find the header file.

Ubuntu 20.04, ROS2 Foxy, C++

Thank you in advance, for any insights that could lead to me overcoming my problem.

**My CmakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(tester123)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

add_executable(main_node src/minimal_publisher_node.cpp src/minimal_publisher.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(main_node rclcpp std_msgs)

install(TARGETS
  main_node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
  
install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
)
  
install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)

ament_package()
```

**Error code (during colcon build)**

```
tester123/src/minimal_publisher.cpp:1:10: fatal error: minimal_publisher.hpp: No such file or directory
1 | #include "minimal_publisher.hpp"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386462/including-custom-header-file-in-ros2-cmakelist/) by [KimJensen](https://answers.ros.org/users/53265/kimjensen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2021-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming your directory structure is something like this,

tester123

- src/
- CMakeLists.txt
- package.xml

Create another directory at `tester123/include/`

Add the `minimal_publisher.hpp` inside the `include` directory.

Before the `add_executable` line in the `CMakeLists.txt`, add the following line

```
include_directories(include)
```

The compiler should be able to find the `minimal_publisher.hpp` now.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2021-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KimJensen](https://answers.ros.org/users/53265/kimjensen/) on 2021-09-20**:
It's usually these small details that I tend to miss. Thank you for your time and the easy to understand answer!